# share encfs folder within the same group

Tags: linux, permissions, mount, group, fuse

given an encfs folder mounted under its own user, is it possible to permit read access to someone else (especially a system user), who belongs to the same group?

For example user1 owns encrypted_folder

user1:group1 - mounted:

```
  $ drwxrwxrwx   user1 group1 encrypted_folder
```

For user2 it looks like:

```
  $ d?????????   ? ? encrypted_folder
```

That leads to an "permission denied" error, if user2 wants to access that folder.

So is it possible to grand user2 access to that folder in order read some files from it? How does it looks like, if user2 is a system user?

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [this encfs flag](http://linux.die.net/man/1/encfs)?

> --public
>
> Attempt to make encfs behave as a typical multi-user filesystem. By default, all FUSE based filesystems are visible only to the user who mounted them. No other users (including root) can view the filesystem contents. The --public option does two things. It adds the FUSE flags "allow_other" and "default_permission" when mounting the filesystem, which tells FUSE to allow other users to access the filesystem, and to use the ownership permissions provided by the filesystem. Secondly, the --public flag changes how encfs's node creation functions work - as they will try and set ownership of new nodes based on the caller identification.
>
> **Warning:** In order for this to work, encfs must be run as root -- otherwise it will not have the ability to change ownership of files. I recommend that you instead investigate if the fuse allow_other option can be used to do what you want before considering the use of --public.